# Concurrency with multiple users accessing the same system (in which system handles requests concurrently)

Tags: multithreading, servlets, concurrency, web, theory

I have a confusing question that I've been thinking about. In the good day scenario of my application I would like to write a `algorithm` that compiles my data for me in `parallel`, and take advantage of speedup. But before I go to all this effort I would like to know if it is possible in this instance, or just a pipe dream.

[image: speed up]
 ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup), 2011)

Lets say for the purposes of this question that I have 5 users (`User A, User B, User C, User D and User E`. These are people who log on with a username/password not a metaphor for threads) logged on within the `SYSTEM` via sessions handled by `Cookies`.

Lets say the `User A` sends a request for the server to calculate a trapezoid of length 1000 by 1000 (and the system divides this request in 4 sections and sends each section to a core). Now lets also say for the purposes of this question `User B` is also logged on at the same time as `User A` and he also sends a request for the system to calculate a trapezoid of a different length (and the system goes and divides that up into the cores of server).

From my brief understanding I know this scenario is obivously  possible with a single user, but is possible with more than 1 user accessing the system concurrently (and having the system handle requests concurrently)? can a java program be written nicely to handle this? or would a `bottle neck` or something else occur between `User A` and `User B` (as they compete for resources from the system) ??? is `User` concurrency  for dealing with large amounts of data best handled in different instantiated objects with `linear algorithms` or can it be done with `parallel algorithms`, with a web based product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Race conditions occur when multiple threads access shared data concurrently. Deadlocks occur when multiple threads lock resources in conflicting order.

These are always possible in a multi-threaded environment but thousands of systems have similar functionality. After I click on "Post Your Answer" button below, SO will be updating the question with answers from multiple users. You don't see any garbage due to race conditions do you?

You would benefit by pseudo-coding the algorithm and seeing where you can achieve concurrency -- one way to do this is by using data that is private to a thread, e.g. local and thread-local variables. Another is to identify (small) sections of code that use shared data and using locking constructs to ensure they don't execute in parallel, allowing rest of code to execute in parallel.

Comment: When I refer to "Users" I'm not referring to a metaphor of threads. Its more of a question about with multiple users on the same application that is completeling requests in parallel.

Comment: I understand your answer, but its in the wrong context. I've updated my question.

Comment: Web based systems are essentially not any different from any other, at least as far as concurrency is concerned. It is not really clear what you are asking.